# Can a Delta table be created using a merge where the source table is empty?

Tags: databricks, delta-lake

I'm trying to use a merge to create an external table in Databricks and I'm getting back an error saying the mnt location is not a Delta table.  The table is created in hive but no data exists in the s3 location yet.  Am I correct to assume we can't create a Delta table using a merge? Or am I missing something else?

The table is created using this:

```
    sql = f"""
        CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hive_metastore.schema.table_name (
            {fields}
            )
            USING DELTA TBLPROPERTIES (delta.enableChangeDataFeed = False) LOCATION '/mnt/.......'
    """
```

and the merge:

```
    df_source_data = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, '/mnt/....')
    df_source_data.alias('scd1') \
      .merge(
        df.alias('updates'),
        primary_keys
      ) \
      .whenMatchedUpdate(
          condition=condition_value,
          set = set_fields
      ) \
      .whenNotMatchedInsert(
          values = set_fields
      ) \
      .execute()
```

I get the following error:

pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.AnalysisException: `/mnt/..../` is not a Delta table.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.  We had another process removing _delta_log/ from the S3 location that we uncovered.

The learning here for us is the following error generally indicates a "table not found" type of error.

pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.AnalysisException: /mnt/..../ is not a Delta table.